# Writing to NSOutputStream cause high cpu usage

Tags: ios, profiling, cpu-usage, nsstream, nsoutputstream

While instrumenting my app I found that CPU usage jumps to 90% when writing data to output stream. Specifically, when network speed is very high. When I profile it With Timer instrument, found that most of the cpu is used for NSStream delegate call. Please Help to optimize writing technic as to low down the cpu usage.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
switch (eventCode) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
        _isConnected = YES;
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(isFTPConnectionFoundForUpload:)])
            [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(isFTPConnectionFoundForUpload:) withObject:_isConnected?@"YES":@"NO"];
    } break;

    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {

            bytesWritten = [self.producerStream write:&self.buffer[0] maxLength:512];
            if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Network write error"];
            }

    } break;

    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
        NSLog(@"producer stream error %@", [aStream streamError]);
        [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {

    } break;
    default: {

    } break;
}
```

}

Comment: Anybody please answer.